# Python - проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: python, apache, кодировка

Помогите разобраться. Запускаю скрипт в Raspberry PI на Python 2.7.9:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Hello"
print "Привет"
print u'Привет'
```

Результат:

Hello

п÷я─п╦п╡п╣я┌

п÷я─п╦п╡п╣я┌

Файл сохранен в кодировке UTF (без BOM). Русский язык в консоле присутствует. Не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: Кодировка консоли какая?

Comment: как эту кодировку правильно посмотреть?          по команде locale выдает                                                                               LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Все дело было в настройках Putty. Нужно было просто установить по умолчанию:
Putty Configuration - Window - Translation:
Received data assumed to be in which character set: = UTF-8. После этого в Python стало отображаться как надо.